# IIS Advanced Logging Counters

Tags: performance, iis, obsolete, azure-application-insights

Is there any experience of IIS Advanced Logger?

I've set it up to work with Application Insights, but the perf counters can't be acceded.http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/idof/2013/08/20/fixing-iis-advanced-logging-performance-counters-errors/, but the suggestion of adding the user to the correct Users group, to no avail.

We use a custom application ID (IISServiceUser), which now has permissions. But the following errors still occur.

```
Failed to initialize performance counter \Process(w3wp)\Private Bytes. Data for this performance counter data will not be recorded until the counter is available. PdhCollectQueryData: 0x0X800007D5.
```

Thoughts??